# Onclick event firing in Firefox and IE but not in Chrome

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-chrome

I have the following javascript function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showhidefields(value,formobj,epsflag,respflag) {
  //alert(epsflag);
  if (epsflag==0 && respflag==4) {
    document.getElementById("tpnr").style.position = "static";
    document.getElementById("tpnr").style.top = "0px";
    formobj.tussenPersoonNotext.disabled =false;
    formobj.email.disabled =true;                  
  }
</script>

<select name="moduleidval" class="validate['required']">
   <option value="">-- Selecteer Proces--</option>
   <option onclick="showhidefields(this.value,this.form,'<?php echo 1; ?>');" 
   value="<?php echo $epsmodules; ?>"><?php echo 'MBO'; ?></option>
</select>
```

My problem is when i click on the option in case of `firefox` or `IE` the onclick event fires but in case of **chrome it doesnot fire at all**.i tried changing the function name also but no luck.

[fiddle](http://jsbin.com/iHEgaQiW/1/edit)

thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**option** elements don't fire the click event in all browsers, you should stray away from relying on this. Instead you can use **onchange()** event for **select**. You may use something like this

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript">

   function changeFunc() {
    var selectBox = document.getElementById("selectBox");
    var selectedValue = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].value;
    alert(selectedValue);
   }

  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <select id="selectBox" onchange="changeFunc();">
   <option value="1">Option #1</option>
   <option value="2">Option #2</option>`enter code here`
  </select>
 </body>`enter code here`
</html>
```

In Your case you use like

```
<form id='myForm' action="#">
  <select id='mySelect' name="moduleidval" class="validate['required']" onchange="showhidefields(this.value,this.form,'0');">
   <option value="-">-- Selecteer Proces--</option>
   <option value="1"> 'Klantprocessen'</option>
</select>
</form>
```

Comment: Use **onchange** to `select` not for `option`

Comment: thanks for this approach,+1 for that but still it doesnot answer my question that why my code is not working but i will accept it :)

Comment: http://jsbin.com/iHEgaQiW/1/edit
here it is,its just a snipett from my actual code.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, there is no `click` event on an option tag.

You may listen to the `onchange` event of the select tag.

```
 <!-- HTML -->
<form id='myForm' action="#">
    <select id='mySelect' name="moduleidval" class="validate['required']">
      <option value="-">-- Selecteer Proces--</option>
      <option value="MBO">MBO</option>
    </select>
</form>

// JavaScript
document.getElementById('mySelect').onchange = function(){
    alert('value:'+this.value); 
    alert('form id:' + this.form.id);
}
```

See Demo [here](http://jsbin.com/IWiHOSe/4/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Paste part of your code on jsbin.com. Maybe you come to another problem. @RishabhRaj

Comment: @RishabhRaj http://jsbin.com/iHEgaQiW/5/edit OK,now. Move onchange=* into the *select* tag. not the option tag.

Answer (score 1):

Few browsers lack in support of onclick event of option tag. Here is the [reference](http://webbugtrack.blogspot.ca/2007/11/bug-280-lack-of-events-for-options.html)
[image]

so you can go for onchange of select tag.

Comment: Uhh... looks like this reference is from year 2007, a lot has changed after that...

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the value directly in the function specified, like:

`<select onchange="trig(value);">`

This value can then be used in the `trig` function.

```
function trig(val) {
    //do foo
    alert(val);
}
```

Short and simple.

A working demo in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/amarprabhu/9C3VU/

Answer (score -3):

Check javascript is enabled in ur chrome.

```
Select Customize and control Google Chrome to the right of the address bar

From the drop-down menu, select Settings

At the bottom of the page, click Show advanced settings…

Under Privacy, click the Content settings… button

Under the JavaScript heading, select the Allow all sites to run JavaScript radio button
```

Comment: i have javascript enabled in my chrome browser